# Editing multiple records at once - how to update without IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Still new to Rails. I'll try to provide as much detail as possible.

I have a form that lets me update multiple records at one time.
It's based off the ['Editing Multiple Individually' Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually).

```
<%= form_tag(auction_clerk_path(@auction), :method => :put) do %>
  <% @lots.each do |lot| %>
    <%= fields_for "lots[]", lot do |f| %>
      <%= f.number_field :sale_price %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

*(Simplified to just include a single input for each instance)*

An *Auction* contains multiple *Lots* (items for sale).
The `auction_clerk_path` is the route I'm using to just show all lots on one auction.

Everything is working just fine... until I use try to customize my lot paths...

I've added the following to my **lot.rb** file to be able to use:
`/auctions/:auction_id/lots/:lot_number`
instead of `/auctions/:auction_id/lots/:id`

```
def to_param
  lot_number
end
```

So, in the form mentioned earlier, the fields render with `name="lots[12][sale_price]"` where `12` is the `id`.

However with the `to_param` change, now the fields render with `name="lots[1][sale_price]"` where 1 is the `lot_number`.

When I save, the submitted parameters are lot_numbers instead of ids.
So obviously when it tries to update, it won't find the correct records.

My method definition looks like this:

```
def save_clerking
  @updated_lots = Lot.update(params[:lots].keys, params[:lots].values).reject { |l| l.errors.empty? }
  if @updated_lots.empty?
    flash[:notice] = "Lots updated"
    redirect_to auction_clerk_path(@auction)
  else
    render :action => "clerk"
  end
end
```

I either need to change my method definition to lookup by lot number, or change the form to somehow output IDs in the first place... but I don't know how.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this through some help on another question.

I changed my method def to

```
@updated_lots = []
params[:lots].each do |lot_number, attributes|
  lot = Lot.where("lot_number = ? AND auction_id = ?", lot_number, params[:auction_id]).first
  if lot.update_attributes(attributes)
    @updated_lots << lot
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the ids by lot number in the controller action and feed those to the update method instead of the params keys.